# Pivot columns with multiple criteria in Power Query

Tags: excel, pivot, powerquery

I have the below source data -

[image: Source]

I'm trying to transform it into -

[image: expected]

I have already tried pivoting the **Type** column in transform tab but this results into multiple rows for each SKU with values for Length, Height and Width in the next rows.

[image: issue]

How can I pivot the data so that I have all the Headers as column names with the unit merged into the value for each header?

Comment: It looks like you could pivot, then Fill up on the Value and Unit columns, then filter out the null rows in the Header column.

Comment: Hi Rory, thank you for your comment, I think this would result into incorrect values being filled down as the values are not always in the diagonal fashion show above.

Comment: As long as the header row comes before the unit and value rows, I don't see the problem. Did it *actually* produce incorrect values?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with this table in excel, named Table1:

[image]

I use this M code...

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SKU", type text}, {"Type", type text}, {"Value", type any}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Type"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index], 3), type number),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Modulo", "Custom", each if Type.Is(Value.Type([Value]),type number) then Text.From([Value]) & " " & #"Inserted Modulo"{[Index]-1}[Value] else null),
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Up", each ([Modulo] = 0)),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index", "Modulo"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[Value]), "Value", "Custom")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

to get this result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "IsHeader", each if [Type]="Header" then [Index] else null),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom2", each if [Type]="Header" then [Value] else null),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom3",{"IsHeader", "Custom2"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Type] <> "Header")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Type]), "Type", "Value"),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column", {{"Value", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Value", "Unit"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter( " ", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Columns",{"IsHeader"}),
#"Pivoted Column1" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns1", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"[Custom2]), "Custom2", "Merged")
in  #"Pivoted Column1"
```